# Web Scraping Satellite Image from publicly available data

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

webpage = 'https://xgis.maaamet.ee/xgis2/page/app/ristipuud'


----------


response = requests.get(site)

bsoup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
img_tags = soup.find_all('img')

urls = \[img\['src'\] for img in img_tags\]

for url in urls:
filename = re.search(r'/(\[\\w\_-\]+\[.\](jpg|gif|tif|png))$', url)
if not filename:
print("didn't match with the url: {}".format(url))
continue
with open(filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:
if 'http' not in url:
url = '{}{}'.format(webpage, url)
response = requests.get(url)
f.write(response.content)`
```

**#code for Lithuania**

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

def download_url(url, save_path, chunk_size=128):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
            fd.write(chunk)

def get_file_name(url):
    tokens = url.split("/")
    file_name = tokens[-1].split("?")[0]
    return file_name

# Start timer
start_time = time.time()
print("Start time: ", start_time)

# Create image directory
image_directory = 'images'
isExist = os.path.exists(image_directory)
if not isExist:
    os.makedirs(image_directory)

template = "https://www.geoportal.lt/map/webapp/rest/mapgateway/6100e156c755e15f6e46a8820824d8c595d30ae51?f=json"

response = requests.get(template)
if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    link = soup.find("a")
    if link is not None:
        url = 'https://www.geoportal.lt/' + link['href']
        file_name = get_file_name(url)
        print(file_name)
        # Save zip file
        download_url(url, './' + image_directory + '/' + file_name)

# End timer
end_time = time.time()

# Calculate elapsed time
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time[![image attached[![\]\[1\]][1]][1]][1]
print("Elapsed time: ", elapsed_time)
```

[Link: https://www.geoportal.lt/map/index.jsp?lang=en](https://www.geoportal.lt/map/index.jsp?lang=en)

I want to download satellite images from this website (link: https://xgis.maaamet.ee/xgis2/page/app/ristipuud). There is about 6000 satellite images in tif format. Among them, I want to get 500 for my research. I have to repeat the same process frequently, so want to get it by scraping. but I am having problem. When I run this code, it doesnt show me any error but it also not downloading any data.  Images on the website are divided into tiles and it can be downloaded separately by searching with the tile number from this link https://geoportaal.maaamet.ee/eng/Maps-and-Data/Orthophotos/Download-Orthophotos-p662.html   . RGB Orthophotos comes in a zip file in .tif format. There are multiple version of the image depending on year and I want to get the latest one. But, unfortunately, my code is not working. Could you please help me to identify mistakes in my code or share your experience. I am novice in coding and trying to learn more.

Comment: Please provide details about what you mean by "my code is not working".

Comment: thanks for the response. When I run this code, it doesnt show me any error but it also not downloading any data.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a tag for the language you are using as well. See [ask] and [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/194720)

Comment: "This code" doesn't run (missing indentation), assuming it is Python.

Comment: just fixed indentation. Now its showing me " didn't match with the url: gfx/logo-maaamet-eng.svg" without downloading any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can download the zipped map files.

```py
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

def download_url(url, save_path, chunk_size=128):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
            fd.write(chunk)

def get_file_name(url):
    tokens = url.split("&")
    for token in tokens:
        if(token[:2] == 'f='):
            return token[2:]
    return ''

# Start timer
start_time = time.time()
print("Start time: ", start_time)

# create image directory     
image_directory = 'images'
isExist = os.path.exists(image_directory)
if not isExist:
   os.makedirs(image_directory)


# get zip URL and file name
start_sheet = 44744
end_sheet = 44844 # you need to change with 74331, I just test 100 range
total_download = 0
for index in range(start_sheet, end_sheet):
    template = "https://geoportaal.maaamet.ee/index.php?lang_id=2&plugin_act=otsing&page_id=662&&kaardiruut={sheet_number:n}&andmetyyp=ortofoto_eesti_rgb"
    webpage = template.format(sheet_number = index)
    response = requests.get(webpage)
    if (response.status_code == 200):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        link = soup.find("a")
        if link is not None:
            url = 'https://geoportaal.maaamet.ee/' + link['href']
            file_name = get_file_name(url)
            print(file_name)
            # save zip file
            download_url(url, './' + image_directory + '/' + get_file_name(url))
            total_download = total_download + 1
# End timer
end_time = time.time()

# Calculate elapsed time
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print("Elapsed time: ", elapsed_time)
print("Total Download zip files: ", total_download)
```

Result after finish

[image]

If unzip, you can see the geoTIFF file.
[image]

Main Idea

As you pointed this URL

```
https://geoportaal.maaamet.ee/eng/Maps-and-Data/Orthophotos/Download-Orthophotos-p662.html
```

[image]

The sheet number range is indicated

```
Map sheet numbers of 1:10000 scale are between 44744 to 74331.
```

In the Chrome(or Firefox), if press `F12` key, `Dev Tool` will show.

The 'Network' tab can see the `https` call at `header` tab.

After open this screen, you can see the request URL when you search with sheet number(44744) by pressing `search` button.

This is the template URL.

```
https://geoportaal.maaamet.ee/index.php?lang_id=2&plugin_act=otsing&page_id=662&&kaardiruut=44744&andmetyyp=ortofoto_eesti_rgb&_=1686945341505
```

[image]

The `kaardiruut` parameter is key to the switch sheet number.

```
kaardiruut=44744
```

To download a program increases its number value for changing another area.

[image]

#### Update for Lithuania with Orthphoto 2021-2013

Lithuania map is not support zip download, it support direct map image download.

This map server is a good example of tile Map

```
https://www.maptiler.com/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/#10/24.70/56.21
```

##### `https://www.geoportal.lt/map` format

```
"https://www.geoportal.lt/map/webapp/rest/mapgateway/{year_id:s}/tile/{scale:n}/{y:n}/{x:n}"
```

##### year_id example

Ortophoto 2021-2023 is '6100e156c755e15f6e46a8820824d8c595d30ae50'

Ortophoto 2018~2020 is '8ddf422a20f8a22fd7c116ef7d6a46eec4126d521'

##### scale = 8 # (1 : 10 000)

##### x (longitude) range for 2021-2023

start_x = min number 8263

end_x = max number 8510

##### y (latitude) range for 2021-2023

start_y = min number 5524

end_y = max number 5839

Demo code

```
import time
import requests
import os
import requests, imghdr

def download_url(image_url, save_path):
    # copy from Chrome's Network Tab/Headers/Request Headers/Cookie
    cookies = {'JSESSIONID_MWEB': '26F90E44851C5CC9CD41E7A1AE056C54;'}
    response = requests.get(url=image_url, cookies=cookies)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        extension = imghdr.what(file=None, h=response.content)
        print(save_path + '.' + extension)
        with open(save_path + '.' + extension, 'wb') as handler:
            handler.write(response.content)
        return True
    return False

def get_file_name(url):
    file_name = url.rsplit('/',1)[1] # file name
    return file_name

def get_directory_name(url):
    x = url.rsplit('/',2)[1]
    scale = url.rsplit('/',3)[1]
    return scale + '/' + x

def create_directory_name(directory_name):
    isExist = os.path.exists(directory_name)
    if not isExist:
        os.makedirs(directory_name)

start_x = 8330 # min number 8263
end_x = 8334   # max number 8510 

start_y = 5635 # min number 5524
end_y = 5640   # max number 5839

total_download = 0

year_id = '6100e156c755e15f6e46a8820824d8c595d30ae50' # Ortophoto 2021-2023
scale = 8 # (1 : 10 000)
# Start timer
start_time = time.time()
print("Start time: ", start_time)

for x_number in range(start_x, end_x):
    for y_number in range(start_y, end_y):
        # ~/{year_id}/tile/{scale}/{y}/{x}
        template = "https://www.geoportal.lt/map/webapp/rest/mapgateway/{year_id:s}/tile/{scale:n}/{y:n}/{x:n}"
        url = template.format(year_id = year_id, scale = scale, y = y_number, x = x_number)
        directory=get_directory_name(url)
        create_directory_name('./' + directory + '/')
        success = download_url(url,  './' + directory + '/' + get_file_name(url))
        if (success == True):
            total_download = total_download + 1

# End timer
end_time = time.time()

# Calculate elapsed time
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print("Elapsed time: ", elapsed_time, " Secs")
print("Total Download tile files: ", total_download)
```

Result
[image]

[image]

I got URL and cookies from Dev Tools
[image]

##### Update distance, geo location and image resolution

You can see the grids over tile and location by meter resolution on left bottom area.
(I found a defect, X and Y is switched)
The unit is meter.

```
https://www.geoportal.lt/map/index.jsp?lang=en
```

[image]

I calculate red rectangle distance by mouse hover with display x, y location capture values. And pasted each point and calculate the distance. (again X, Y needs to switch - that was bug)

```
X distance = 3,909 m (yellow color)
Y distance = 4,637 m (green color)
```

[image]

Back to our program to figure out how much tile's resolution

All of tile (256 * 256) pixels image - that is a small size file.

Re-run my program for getting that area

```
start_x = 8416 # min number 8263
end_x = 8424   # max number 8510 

start_y = 5604 # min number 5524
end_y = 5611   # max number 5839
```

Got this result

[image]

I will calculate how much pixel size is the real-world distance?
the red crossed width of late is 1092 meters
(I measured mouse hover by the left bottom area tool)
delta X = 582123 - 581031 = 1092 m

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
total pixels 418 pixels = 56 + 256 + 106
pixel per meter = 1085 m/ 418 px= 2.59 m/pixel
```

So my calculation is 2.5 m/pixel. (guessing)

1 tile size = 256 pixels * 256 pixels = 640 m * 640 m

If you many images, example 20000 * 20000 pixels (like ESTIJA's GeoTiff), like 78 tiles * 78 tiles
It will be high-resolution images.

I hope this my guessing is matched the real size. Good luck!
I have no more time to spend on this question.  Other areas investigate by yourself.

Comment: it is working perfectly, I appreciate your efforts. Would you mind sharing how you made template " https://geoportaal.maaamet.ee/index.php?lang_id=2&plugin_act=otsing&page_id=662&&kaardiruut={sheet_number:n}&andmetyyp=ortofoto_eesti_rgb"  .  It would be very helpful for me for future reference to get image from other webpage.

Comment: @MizanurRahman, I updated my answer to explain the template URL. How to get it. and why that range from 44744 to 74331.

Comment: I got it. that was very helpful for me. appreciate

Comment: I applied the same code for Latvia, and it worked perfectly. Now I was trying to use the same code for to get images for Lithuania. But here, data type is JSON. I tried to get information using developer tool and did not fine anything which I can use to get into specific. link: https://www.geoportal.lt/map/index.jsp?lang=en . In the portal, on the right, orthophotos can be selected. From the developers tool,  I used this url: https://www.geoportal.lt/map/webapp/rest/mapgateway/6100e156c755e15f6e46a8820824d8c595d30ae51?f=json. what can I do to get all images? your thoughts? TIA

Comment: when I zoom in or zoom out, orthophotos on the webpage, its seems like image are stored in tiles. But I am having difficulty to get tiles number or anything related to tiles.

Comment: @MizanurRahman, can your provide URL for Lativia and Lithuania? or how to reproduce your problem?

Comment: can you update your question with screen shut and URL with Lithuania?

Comment: I attached the edited code from your previous suggestion. Here, files are not stored in tiles and data type is JSON.  This case, what keyword or links i should look for to get the image link to download? This code runs without any error but not giving any output. webpage [url](https://www.geoportal.lt/map/webapp/rest/mapgateway/6100e156c755e15f6e46a8820824d8c595d30ae51?f=json) .

Comment: [orthophoto](https://www.geoportal.lt/map/index.jsp?lang=en)

Comment: That URL did not show anything by chrome even the `44744` URL shows list of ZIP files. ( I updated my answer). So Lithuania URL is no response from server. It is meaningless. How to get that URL address, how to search Lithuania URL, I needs to know how and screen shut like my red rectangle screen. Can you show it?

Comment: Do you want to this kind of [tile image](https://www.geoportal.lt/mapproxy/gisc_pagrindinis/MapServer/tile/10/5688/8320)?

Comment: It seems support only ESTIJA in this [URL](https://xgis.maaamet.ee/xgis2/page/link/LT-2utO4), you can see zoom in/out the tile bound with blue rectangle.

Comment: I tried to upload screenshot. But unfortunately, its not now showing. this a google drive link, where shored the screenshots. [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18VWA0cw6j3ATYPa1vcGJzLnlzHComdJ0?usp=sharing) . Yes, like this image, but I want orthophoto. on the website, there is section for orthophoto on the upper right side. I also added one photo how downloaded photo could be.

Comment: actually the link you gave me, its for Estonia. This is the actual link for Lithuania [link](https://www.geoportal.lt/map/index.jsp?lang=en).

Comment: OK, I get that image in DevTools, you want to all of Lithuania with Orthphoto 2021-2013.
There are many scale, which scales example (1: 10 000, 1: 25 000)?

Comment: I only want any image from 2021-2023 at 1:10000 scale.  could you please share the code and give me a screenshot as well, how exactly you found it.

Comment: OK, I will try it will a time after return home.

Comment: sure. take your time.

Comment: @MizanurRahman, I update for Lithuania image download.

Comment: thank you so much. It appreciate it. your explanation was very helpful to understand the concept. Its working perfectly. Only thing i am concerned, resolution of the downloaded is not very good. Is there any way to get better resolution and georeferenced ? TIA

Comment: the image size is very small, it varies from 7 to 20kb. I uploaded some images in google drive  which  added earlier. Could you please have a look when you get some time. [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18VWA0cw6j3ATYPa1vcGJzLnlzHComdJ0?usp=sharing)

Comment: I updated again your additional question. Good luck!